# MongoDB: how to update a nested array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have collection with data:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid":"5c3334a8871695568817ea26" },
  "country":"Afghanistan",
  "code":"af",
  "region":[
    {
      "path":["Afghanistan"],
      "_id":{"$oid":"5c3366bd3d92ac6e531dfb43"},
      "name":"Badakhshan",
      "city":[]
    },
    ...
  ]
},
```

And I need to add cities (Array) inside city field.
My model looks like this:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  country: { type: String },
  code: { type: String },
  region: [{
    name: { type: String },
    path: { type: Array },
    city: [{
      name: { type: String },
      path: { type: Array },
      latitude: { type: String },
      longitude: { type: String },
    }],
  }],
})
```

I send query

```
Model.updateOne(
  { code: country.code },
  { $push: { 'region.city': { $each: savedCities } } },
)
.exec()
```

and receive the error MongoError: Cannot create field 'city' in element {region: [.....
What is my mistake?
I look similar topics but not found the answer.

Comment: Do you want to add that cities to every region or to this particular one (Badakhshan) ?

Comment: To particular. Thanks I did not specific where to save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to indicate which element od `region` array should be updated, try:

```
Model.updateOne(
    { code: country.code, 'region.name': 'Badakhshan' },
    { $push: { 'region.$.city': { $each: savedCities } } },
)
```